# Provide generic class instead of a mapper class while executing an API using resttemplate

Tags: spring, rest, resttemplate, rest-assured

I'm trying to write an integration test for one of the API, but however it returns a XML object, where I don't have any corresponding class inorder to map. How can I do without any class?

Here is my code

```
HttpHeaders authHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
authHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
authHeaders.add("Authorization", "Bearer "+oAuthToken );

UriComponentsBuilder builder=UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(PES_END_POINT + PES_RESOURCE)

   .queryParam("count", "100")
   .queryParam("app-name", "bb")


 HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(authHeaders);

 Object response = restTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.POST, entity , Class<T> ); --> Here what generic class can I provide?
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

just use the [ObjectMapper](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-objectmapper.html)

```
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.POST, entity , String.class); 
        JavaType javaType = objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructType(yourClass);
        YourGenericClass<T> result = objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody(), javaType);
```